# Matching the array using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, nodes

```js
let arr= ["Product",["car","Bike"]];
let out= arr[1].map((rest)=>[arr[0],rest]);
console.log(out);
```

so I am getting my output as

```
[[Product , car],
 [Product , bike]],
```

I can do this with above code as my output is simple but I don't know how to do this output

```
[["product",["car","Bike","truck"]],
 ["Milk",["cheese","butter","curd"]],
 ["Animals",["Lion","Tiger"]]]
```

As I tried same code on this output but getting this

```js
let arr= [["product",["car","Bike","truck"]],
 ["Milk",["cheese","butter","curd"]],
 ["Animals",["Lion","Tiger"]]];
 let out= arr[1].map((rest)=>[arr[0],rest]);
 console.log(out);
```

as my expected output follow like this:

```
[Product car]
[Product bike]
[Product truck]
[Milk cheese]
[Milk butter]
[Milk curd]
[Animal Lion]
[Animal Tiger]
```

any chances I can get each object separated like expected Output ? not like this

```
[[Product car]
 [Product bike]
 [Product truck]
 [Milk cheese]
 [Milk butter]
 [Milk curd]
 [Animal Lion]
 [Animal Tiger]]
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? You can do an `array.flat(1)` for the "expected output" from the last code block but I don't think that your code is giving the mentioned output.

Comment: as I know @Abhijit :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the final array you desire.

```
let arr= [["product",["car","Bike","truck"]],
     ["Milk",["cheese","butter","curd"]],
     ["Animals",["Lion","Tiger"]]];

 let array =[];

 for(let i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
        let out = arr[i][1].map(rest =>[arr[i][0],rest])
        array.push(out)
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need nested loops. The inner loop is like your original `map()`, the outer loop can use `flatMap()` to concatenate the results of the inner loops.

```js
let arr = [
  ["product", ["car", "Bike", "truck"]],
  ["Milk", ["cheese", "butter", "curd"]],
  ["Animals", ["Lion", "Tiger"]]
];
let out = arr.flatMap(([first, rest]) => rest.map(el => [first, el]));
console.log(out);
```